# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /folder-name/ on this server

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I was looking for an answer to my problem, but I could'nt find any answer which solves my case.

The problem is that I can't access the app folders in my var/www/ folder. When I go to localhost/ i get the message that my server is running and I have access to phpmyadmin too. But when I go to any localhost/folder-name i get the 403 error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /folder-name/ on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

How can I solve it? Btw I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, and thanks for your answers. :)

Comment: You might want to post your the vhost section of your apache config, so people can check what you've configured and hopefully spot what's incorrect!

Comment: Do you mean this? http://pastebin.com/q8R1p9sb

Comment: Nope, we need this bit where the vhost is defined. That looks to just be the snippet that imports the file with the vhost

Comment: Place an index.html inside that folder and see if that allows you to visit it. If it does you have -Indexes options which means you won't be able to list any folders.

Comment: It has the default index.html and it does work, how can I fix that? And here's my entire .conf http://pastebin.com/RZcEszzx

Comment: @sakas `.htaccess` on the root folder of your virtualhost place this at the top: `Options +Indexes`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Solved the problem with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/folder-name

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Grant permissions

Comment: It didn't worked for me. I'm getting chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink `phpmyadmin'

Answer (score 17):

under `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, you can find one or more blocks that describe the server directories and permissions

As an example, this is the default configuration

```xml
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

you can replicate this but change the directory path `/var/www/` with the new directory.

Finally, you need to restart the apache server, you can do that from a terminal with the command: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: This worked for me. Just need to place Allowoverride to Non on the virtual host file. The apache config file does not have directory so need to put that in the vhost file

Answer (score 6):

if permission issue and you have ssh access in root folder

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

will resolve your error

Comment: What the heck is this doing?

Comment: Giving permissions in this way, resolve issues when some time not resolved by conventional way

Answer (score 1):

**403 Forbidden **

You don't have permission to access /Folder-Name/ on this server**

The solution for this problem is:

1.go to etc/apache2/apache2.conf

2.find the below code and change AllowOverride all to AllowOverride none

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all      Change this to--->  AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

It will work fine on your Ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue using below steps :

## 1) edit file "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf"

```
    DocumentRoot "dir_name"

    ServerName <server_IP>

    <Directory "dir_name">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "dir_name">
       AllowOverride None
       # Allow open access:
       Require all granted
```

2) change folder permission 
sudo chmod -R 777 "dir_name"