# localhost/magento2/setup page error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

When i want to go to that url,

i get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /magento2/setup on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

i added this

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento2>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to the

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

this is diirectory

```
sudo ls /var/www/html/magento2/
app      COPYING.txt          LICENSE_AFL.txt      pub
bin      dev              LICENSE.txt      setup
CHANGELOG.md     Gruntfile.js.sample  nginx.conf.sample    update
composer.json    index.php        package.json.sample  var
composer.lock    ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md    php.ini.sample       vendor
CONTRIBUTING.md  lib              phpserver
```

i tried a lot of things

this is php

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

this is mysql

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2# mysql -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 465
Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

this is apache2

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2#
```

there seems no errors with those.

when i go to

```
http://localhost/magento2/setup
```

i got error.

i changed to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/magento2>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but nothing changed, extra line added to the error.

i also changed permissions described here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18950561/6690056

and here

```
Make files and directories writable:

To make files and directories writable so you can update components and upgrade the Magento software:

Log in to your Magento server.
Change to your Magento installation directory.
Enter the following commands:

chmod -R u+w .
```

but now i get only pag with php code despite localhost shows true page:

for http://localhost/magento2/setup/

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    echo "You cannot run this from the command line." . PHP_EOL .
        "Run \"php bin/magento\" instead." . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

// For Setup Wizard we are using our customized error handler
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);

\Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require __DIR__ . '/config/application.config.php')->run();
```

what can be reason?

Comment: Please add permission to folder then try

Comment: i did this? chmod -R u+w

Comment: `sudo chmod -Rf 777 <folder name>`

Comment: also <?php
 phpinfo();
?> is shown :/ this is about php