# Forbidden HTTP server access

Tags: http, unix, server, chmod

Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access /~bb/aa/cc/ on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxxxxxxxxx Port 80
```

Hi

I am working on constructing a personal page on the server but cannot access it.
Here is my file address.

```
~/home/bb/html/aa/cc
```

the chmod changed all of the directories I had to: 
`drwx--x--x` and the files including index.html to `-rw-r--r-- 1`

I don't know why I am not able to access this website.

Comment: Could you give more information to what "~" expands to? Which server you're using and possibly the configuration of the server.

Comment: i think this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948996/403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-folder-name-on-this-server